# How to create a generated field in DataStudio from two field in a row

Tags: looker-studio

I need to find a way to select two fields in DataStudio and apply a function to them to generate a third one.

The restriction I have is that the only information that DataStudio can use is the one on that row.

So I have

```
Column 1| Column 2| Column 3
X       |Y        | X+Y
```

But the problem is that DataStudio keeps giving me problems because it tries to aggregate the information of all the column instead of just applying what it has in that row to the column in the same row.

Is it possible to do what I want in DataStudio?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achive what you're looking for by making `Column 1` and `Column 2` have an `AggregationType` of `None` or `No Aggregation`. See [Aggregation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7354634?hl=en) and [About Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en) for more information.

Comment: The problem with that is that there is already some aggregation working on each of the rows that I am using. So, under the hood, that row is more than one row for DataStudio although it's only one after the aggregations are done